# Is is possible to bring to front webkit browser with Playwright?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, ui-automation, playwright

I am currently developing an automation app, I started using Playwright as I honestly think that this library is awesome ! However I was wondering, is it possible to bring to front a browser through code when needed ?

Thank you in advance,

Volck

Comment: Are you asking if there are alternatives for this library? Or if you can do it natively?

Comment: I was asking if it is possible to bring to front a browser opened with and controlled by Playwright.

Comment: What does 'bring to front' mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant by 'bring to front' is : for example, if I launch a new browser (using Playwright) and then, I minimize it, is it possible to bring it to front, to show it again, when needed through code ?

Comment: While there is no API for this, I would like to call out that the browsers and pages behave as if they are visible and active, even if they are in the background. If that's not working for you, can you please help file an issue? https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues